# gettext: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No translation file found for domain: 'base'

Tags: python, gnu, gettext

It seems that I am unable to get my GNU gettext utility to work properly, despite closely following both documentation and online resources.

My folder structure is the following:

```
/
|- src
|    |- __init__.py
|    |- main.py
|- locales
     |- ru
          |- LC_MESSAGES
               |- base.mo
               |- base.po
```

the top of my main.py reads like this (Windows machine):

```
import argparse
import gettext
from gettext import gettext as _

argparser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
argparser.add_argument("--language", required=False, default="en")
arguments = argparser.parse_args()
gettext.translation(
    "base", localedir=r".\locales", languages=[arguments.language[:2]]
).install()
```

And yet, when I try to run the script in either English or Russian, I still get an error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No translation file found for domain: 'base'
```

What am I doing wrong?

I've tried putting `locales` dir inside the `src` folder and dropping the dot prefix (`gettext.translation("base", localedir=r"locales", ...`), but it doesn't seem to have changed anything.

EDIT: adding `fallback=True` seems to have worked, but translation does not seem to process. You can find details to reproduce [here](https://discuss.python.org/t/gettext-filenotfounderror-errno-2-no-translation-file-found-for-domain-base/20856/10?u=vovavili).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve my problem by doing the combination of the following, not sure which exact thing has helped:

1. Specifying the absolute path with `pathlib.Path(__file__).resolve().parents[1] / "locale"` instead of a simple string with a dot.
2. Not overwriting the underscore after install - `from gettext import gettext as _` has to be removed, and to silence the PyCharm linter I use this trick:

```
from gettext import gettext as _

def main() -> None:
    gettext.translation(...).install()
    del globals()["_"]  # Keep PyCharm happy
```

3. Locale has to be a list - `[ru]`, not `ru`.